# RewriteRule creating 500 Internal Server Error bad flag delimiters

Tags: mod-rewrite

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /login/

RewriteRule /login/(.*)$ /php/login/$1

Comment: I need the result like this...
login/index to php/login/index.php

Answer (score 0):

I am not a htaccess expert but I think the error is in your last line.
Try replacing this line of htaccess

```
RewriteRule /login /php/login $1.php
```

with this

```
RewriteRule /login/ /php/login.php
```

I am guessing that you want to rewrite from /login/ to /php/login.php